# Laravel Delete function not working using ajax

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

Hi im using datatable and need to delete multiple data using checkbox, I'm using post method javascript,

Controller

```
 public function deleteselected(Request $request){
    $ids = $request->ids;
    Product::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
    return response()->json(['code'=>1, 'msg'=>'Products have been deleted from database']); 
 }
```

Javascript

```
                       $.post(url,{countries_ids:checkedCountries, _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", _method: "POST"},function(data){
                          if(data.code == 1){
                              $('#geniustable').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, true);
                              toastr.success(data.msg);
                          }

                       },'json');
```

Error

```
{
    "message": "Function () does not exist",
    "exception": "ReflectionException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/lifespace/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php",
    "line": 22,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/lifespace/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteSignatureParameters.php",
            "line": 22,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "ReflectionFunction",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

Comment: post your `route` and `url` details here.

Comment: Route::post('/products/deleteall', 'Admin\ProductController@deleteselected')->name('delete-selected');

Comment: var url = '{{ route("delete-selected") }}';

Comment: which version of laravel ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra it's working now, thanks for your effort. now I'm used ajax call.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where is the `toastr` variable coming from `toastr.success(data.msg)`? Can you add all relevant coded please. Also can you code format the error message also please so it's easier to read. Thanks